# How does one transform a vector from one coordinate system to another?

Tags: linear-transformations

I know a point can be translated to new position in new coordinate system just by translation with difference of old origin to new origin.

How does this work with Vectors?

I know we need to rotate too in case of vectors if the new coordinate system is oriented differently but a little unclear how the translated vector would look like. For example: Say vector from origin to (3,4), would it result in a vector from new origin to new_position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think things are much clearer if you differentiate between a vector (an object) and its coordinates (its representation).

When we talk about a vector, say in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we mean a specific point in it. When we talk intuitively about the coordinates of a vector, this is just actually just shorthand for its "parts" with respect to other vectors (the basis) which we have fixed as "building blocks."

For example, with the usual $\mathbb{R^2}$, the standard basis is $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0  \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1  \end{bmatrix}$. Then, a vector, say $\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}$ is actually $$\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}=5\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0  \end{bmatrix}+6\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1  \end{bmatrix}.$$ In this case, the vector is no different to its coordinates.

When we change coordinates, we change our reference point (our building blocks; our basis) but not the vector itself. For example, if instead I use the vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0  \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1  \end{bmatrix}$ as basis, the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}$ is now represented by the coordinates $\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\6  \end{bmatrix}$ since $$\begin{bmatrix}5 \\6  \end{bmatrix} = -1\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0  \end{bmatrix} + 6\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1  \end{bmatrix}.$$

The coordinates tell us how much of each building block we need as these are the components that make up our vector.

If you wanted a slightly more involved explanation: When working with linear spaces, these transformations of coordinates are typically handled by change of basis matrices $P$. These represent the identity map with respect to different bases $B$ and $D$. What these do is that they take the coordinates of a vector $v$ in $B$ and then output the coordinates of $v$ with respect to $D$.

In symbols, with $P=[id]_{B,D}$, $$[id_{B,D}][v]_B = [v]_D.$$

As an example, let $B$ be the standard basis, $D =\lbrace \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0  \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1  \end{bmatrix} \rbrace$ and $v=\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}.$ 
We then have $P=[id]_{B,D}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\0&1  \end{bmatrix}$.

The coordinates of $\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}$ with respect to $D$ are then given by $$[\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}]_D = P[v]_B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\0&1  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -1\\6  \end{bmatrix}$$ as we have obtained prior.

If you want to visualize these, think of rotating, changing the angle between or stretching the $x$ and $y$ axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then find the coordinates of a vector with respect to the squished and rotated coordinates. You can also easily add translations, although these are no longer linear in the strict sense (linear operations fix the origin). If you involve translations, the transformations you are looking at for changes of coordinates will be called "affine".

For more basic information, I suggest the introductory book by Jim Heffron on linear algebra, which is readily available for free online: https://hefferon.net/linearalgebra/. It is a friendly read and has many examples and exercises.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it helped! Will look into the link too.